# В Tkinter как создать полосу прокрутки подстраиваемого размера?

Tags: python, tkinter

Пишу приложение, используя библиотеку Tkinter языка Python. В созданном окне есть фрейм, в нем - текстовое поле и под ним 2 кнопки. Необходимо слева расположить полосу прокрутки бегунка так, чтобы ее размер соответствовал заданным параметрам текстового поля.

Пока получилось только создать полосу, которая - в силу первоначального (при запуске программы) отсутствия текста в поле - подстраивает поле под себя (уменьшает) и вертикально встает по его центру (делит текстовую область на 2 половины).

Как исправить досадное упущение?

```
# рамка, где будет поле для вопросов пользователя
frame_question_answer = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5
)
# Данная область предназначена для написания вопросов
text_box_question = tk.Text(
    master=frame_question_answer,
    width=67, 
    height=5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)
# ...

# создаем полосу прокрутки текстовой области
scrollbar_question = tk.Scrollbar(text_box_question,
#                                 frame_question_answer,
                                 orient='vertical', 
                                  command=text_box_question.yview   # первая привязка
                                 )
scrollbar_question.grid(sticky='e')
# вторая привязка
text_box_question.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_question.set)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S. Nick, ниже в ответе изложено. На будущее учту писать более развернуто. Спасибо за реакцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто для полосы прокрутки и текстового поля, когда размещаете их, надо указать из ряд и столбец. Также растянуть текстовое поле во все стороны `sticky='news'`, а полосу прокрутки достаточно только по вертикали `sticky='ns'`. И оба элемента размещать, конечно, в их общем фрейме.

Как-то так:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# рамка, где будет поле для вопросов пользователя
frame_question_answer = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5
)
frame_question_answer.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True) # фрейм размещаем так чтобы заполнял всё пространство

# Данная область предназначена для написания вопросов
text_box_question = tk.Text(
    master=frame_question_answer,
    width=67, 
    height=5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)
text_box_question.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='news')

# создаем полосу прокрутки текстовой области
scrollbar_question = tk.Scrollbar(frame_question_answer,
                                  orient='vertical', 
                                  command=text_box_question.yview   # первая привязка
                                 )
scrollbar_question.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')

# вторая привязка
text_box_question.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_question.set)

btn = tk.Button(window, activebackground='red', text="Press me")
btn.pack()

text_box_question.insert(tk.END, "Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5\nLine6\nLine7\nLine8\n")

window.mainloop()
```

[image: -]

Если хотите, чтобы текстовое поля изменялось вместе с окном, то добавьте "веса" той ячейке, что содержит это поле.

```
frame_question_answer.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_question_answer.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

Comment: Код отработал полноценно. Кстати у меня frame в grid обернут, поэтому параметр fill=tk.BOTH заменил на sticky="ew"

Comment: @АлексейКазанцев Ну вы же не предоставили в примере чем вы размещали frame. Поэтому пришлось додумывать.

Comment: вот еще какой момент: когда к одному из текстовых полей прикрутил скрол, поле сжелось внутри фрейма, поскольку в grid нет параметра expand. Параметра sticky='news' оказалось недостаточно. Что можно предпринять?

Comment: @АлексейКазанцев Надо на конкретный код код смотреть. Я ж не знаю как и чего там накручено.